# Sort by field from jsonb column

Tags: npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I'm using npgsql to store data about shipments and part of table is jsonb column storing some details about shipment including details about customer who made shipment.

Table for displaying data about shipments is displaying only Customer Name and  if get that record via

```
 CustomerName = shipment.Metadata.RootElement.GetProperty("customer").GetProperty("customerName").ToString(),
```

Request is that I make this column sortable so I would need to sort by this property while accessing database.

Is it even possible to do it in NpgSql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily sort by a property inside a JSON document - just specify that property in your OrderBy clause:

```cs
_ = await ctx.Shipments
    .OrderBy(s => s.Metadata.RootElement.GetProperty("customer").GetProperty("customerName").GetString())
    .ToListAsync();
```

This produces the following:

```sql
SELECT s."Id", s."Metadata"
FROM "Shipments" AS s
ORDER BY s."Metadata"#>>'{customer,customerName}'
```

You should probably be able to make this use an index as well.